# Care to review my first hash map?

Tags: c#

This is my first attempt at a hash map and I feel it is a great start. Although it does have a certain naive feel that I'm having trouble with.

```
public class HashMap<TKey, TValue>
{
    const int BlockSize = 100000;
    const int NumberOfBlocks = 42950;

    readonly Entry[][] _blocks = new Entry[NumberOfBlocks][];
    readonly IEqualityComparer<TKey> _comparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;


    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {           
        uint hashCode = (uint)_comparer.GetHashCode(key);
        int blockIndex = (int)(hashCode / BlockSize);
        int slotIndex = (int)(hashCode - blockIndex * BlockSize);

        var block = _blocks[blockIndex];
        if (block == null)
        {
            block = _blocks[blockIndex] = new Entry[BlockSize];
        }

        var entry =  block[slotIndex];
        if (entry == null)
        {
            entry = block[slotIndex] = new Entry(key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            while (entry != null && entry.Next != null)
            {
                if (_comparer.Equals(key, entry.Key))
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                entry = entry.Next;
            }
            entry = entry.Next = new Entry(key, value);
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        uint hashCode = (uint)_comparer.GetHashCode(key);
        int blockIndex = (int)(hashCode / BlockSize);
        int slotIndex = (int)(hashCode - blockIndex * BlockSize);

        var block = _blocks[blockIndex];
        if (block == null)
            return false;

        var entry = block[slotIndex];
        while (entry != null)
        {
            if (_comparer.Equals(key, entry.Key))
                return true;
            entry = entry.Next;
        }
        return false;
    }

    class Entry
    {
        public readonly TKey Key;
        public readonly TValue Value;
        public Entry Next;

        public Entry(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be a good idea to implement [IDictionary<TKey,TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx), and maybe using `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`s as entries instead of your custom `Entry`?

Comment: @codesparkle - I briefly thought about using `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` but I wanted each slot to work also as a singly linked list so that collisions could be handled simply. As for `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` I wanted to keep things simple so I could focus on the logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm assuming you're implementing your own hashtable as an exercise/kata instead of using the CLR's, as I haven't seen anything unique here that justifies rolling your own.)

Here's some feedback:

1. `HashMap` should implement core interfaces and functionality as other .NET containers do (e.g.: `IEnumerable<T>`, `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`, provide an enumerator implementation). As a guide, look at the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class and see what interfaces it implements. I'd expect your code to have a similar level of service;
2. `_blocks` should be a `List` instead of an array, and its capacity (`NumberOfBlocks`) should be passed optionally through an optional constructor argument. Same applies to the equality comparer. Notice that these initial values seem very, very high - allocating a 42950-Entry[] array right off the bet for an empty container, and an additional 100,000 Entry array at first addition;
3. Why cast `hashCode` to `uint`?
4. Notice the duplicate code between `Add` and `ContainsKey`. This should be cleanly refactored;
5. `blockIndex`'s and `slotIndex`'s calculations do not seem correct. For example, you are dividing by 100,000, so this will work because `int.MaxValue < 100000 * 100000`. However, if you make this configurable and a lower value is used, you could go past your `_blocks` size. You should use modulo instead of division. Also, `slotIndex` will always be zero (or 1 due to rounding) as `(hashCode - blockIndex * BlockSize) == (hashCode - hashCode/BlockSize * BlockSize) == (hashCode - hashCode) == 0`. `NumberOfBlocks` is not used at all here, which is weird;
6. You should use `LinkedList` instead of rolling your own linked list (again, I'm assuming you're writing some exercise code, otherwise it's a must). Or at least you should define properties instead of exposing the values as public members;
7. Don't throw `Exception`. Create your own custom exception with a proper name;
8. Setting the entry variable in the if statement in `Add` is needless and just reduces readability.
9. The while loop in `Add` is a bit weird. Why do you need to check `entry` and `entry.Next`? I think you meant `entry.Next` only.
10. Setting entry at the end of the while look is needless and just reduces readability. I'd actually rename `entry` to `previous` for clarity.

Did you write any unit tests for this? Make sure you do so.

EDIT: typo: CRL => CLR